# Plot derivatives of sin(x) using pytorch

Tags: pytorch, autograd

Am unsure why my code does not plot cos(x) (yes, am aware pytorch has cos(x) function)

```
import math
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = torch.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, 5000, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.sin(x)
y.backward(x)
x.grad == torch.cos(x) # assert x.grad same as cos(x)
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), y.detach().numpy(), label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label='cos(x)') # print derivative of sin(x)
```

Comment: What do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to feed the upstream gradient (equals to all ones in your case) instead of `x` as input to `y.backward()`.

Thus

```py
import math
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = torch.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, 5000, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.sin(x)
y.backward(torch.ones_like(x))
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), y.detach().numpy(), label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x.detach().numpy(), x.grad.detach().numpy(), label='cos(x)') # print derivative of sin(x)
plt.show()
```